# Create a temporary folder without unique name (python - tempfile)

Tags: python, temporary-files

I want to create a temporary folder without a unique name (with mkdtemp, create a temporary folder with a unique name with 6 random letters). I want to rename this folder to find it in other file.

```
folder_temp = tempfile.mkdtemp(suffix='', prefix='tmp', dir='../addons/static/src/')
with open(folder_temp + '/data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(partners_map, outfile)
```

I try to rename with:

```
os.rename(folder_temp, 'ggm.tmp')
```

or:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for directory in dirs:
        path1 = '%s\%s' % (path, directory)
        new_path = '%s\%s' % (path, new_name)
        os.rename(path1, new_path)
```

But without success.

Please, how to make a folder temporary /tmp and not /tmp****** ?
Tanks.

Comment: Why not making a normal folder under /tmp/ and then deleting it when you're done?

Comment: What's the problem here? WHat's not working as intended?

Comment: It's a cloud solution and it's to avoid permission conflict. All working but i want to set my own folder name not a random name. And I can't to rename this folder.

Comment: On a standard operating system, every user should have permissions to create files and folders in `/tmp`. What is the output of `ls -ld /tmp`?

Answer (score 2):

You can make your own directory within standard OS temporary directory:

```
import tempfile
import os
myTempFolder = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), 'myApplicationTemp')
os.makedirs(myTempFolder)
print (myTempFolder)
```

Prints:

```
/tmp/myApplicationTemp
```

Comment: Yes, but I don't have permission on /tmp an i can't modify this. Therefore I want to build a temporary folder in other dir. When, I use tempfile.mkdtemp(), I have a folder with random letters after the name folder: myTempFolderOHvdct/